# Chamisha Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred and five?

### ?חמישה ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 305.

Don't be led astray like a lamb by lazy gematria.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous three hundred and four entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hashem's name יֱהֹוִה (pronounced אֱלֹהִים) occurs 305 times in Tanach .

Comment: How do you count those? Can you search by vowelized text?

Comment: http://www.davka.com/cgi-bin/product.cgi?product=367&source=DWCOMSITE

Answer (score 4):

There are approximately 305K letters in a [Torah scroll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_Torah#Production).

Comment: A more interesting source IMO http://www.aishdas.org/toratemet/en_pamphlet9.html

Comment: The number they give (304805) is based (they claim) on the Masora of Ben Asher in his Dikdukei Taamim. Can anyone confirm that our received text has the same number?

Comment: @DoubleAA [Here's](http://torahmusings.com/2012/10/letters-of-the-torah/) something posted today on Hirhurim that indicates another source for the same total. Anyway, it'd have to be off by hundreds to remove the association with 305.

Answer (score 2):

In 1929 - 305 American Jews made Aliya. [source - jta.org](http://archive.jta.org/article/1930/10/06/2786604/305-american-jews-settled-in-palestine-in-1929)