# Shemona Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred and eight?

### ?שמונה ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 308.

If you feel the need to discuss lazy gematria, please resist.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous three hundred and seven entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Comment: [Well...](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22364)

Comment: @msh210 - It's up to you. Personally, [I'd consider](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/21927/2) rounding a more natural convention than flooring to get from a number expressed in units to an integer number of thousands.

Comment: Well, it's at half a thousand: rounding up or down is only a convention anyway. So 307 is the floor and round and 308 is the ceiling and round. Sorta. But "307" is mentioned in words in the _pasuk_. So I think I'll not post it here. Of course, anyone else can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [Rabbi Elazar of Vermaiza (1165-1240)](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%99%D7%96%D7%90) published the Sefer HaRokeach ספר
>   הרקח. He called it Sefer HaRokeach since both Elazar - his name, and Rokeach = 308

In one of his Seforim פירוש רבינו אלעזר מגרמייזא על התורה ועל מגילת אסתר פ’ קרח טז:א he says that Korach was upset about Elazar being given the position of נשיא נשיאי הלוי (Bamidbar 3:32) and he said that Elazar is equivalent to me, even our names are both equal since both (קרח & אלעזר) Elazar and Korach = 308.

Comment: +1 Wow! I know comments aren't meant for this, but you really have lots of knowledge (or extraordinary search capabilities)